# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'stripe_customer_id'

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am receiving the error below when attempting to submit a purchase using stripe api within django app.

> line 115, in post
>       if userprofile.stripe_customer_id != '' and userprofile.stripe_customer_id is not None: AttributeError: 'tuple'
>   object has no attribute 'stripe_customer_id' [09/Oct/2019 19:18:26]
>   "POST /api/checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16291

Everything was working until i made alterations based on [22:33](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaJ-b0ZaSoI&t=56s).

This is line 115:

```
 if userprofile.stripe_customer_id != '' and userprofile.stripe_customer_id is not None:
            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(
                userprofile.stripe_customer_id)
            customer.sources.create(source=token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've posted *far* too much code here.

The problem is here:

```
userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
```

[`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns a tuple: `(object, created)`. You've assigned the whole tuple to the `userprofile` variable.

Since you don't care about `created`, assign it to a throwaway name:

```
userprofile, _ = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
```